# How to use Command module in Ansible while domain joining the linux servers?

Tags: ansible

We are trying use realm for domain integration for our linux servers

I am trying to use below code in playbook using command module but getting an error:

```
- name: install pexpect using pip
  shell: /bin/bash -c "pip install pexpect"

- name: Join system to AD 
  expect:
    command: "{{ item }}"
    loop:
      - source /etc/os-release
      - realm join --membership-software=adcli --user=username@EXAMPLE.COM --computer-ou="OU={{ env }},OU={{ account }},OU=XXXX,OU=XXXXXX,DC=XXXXXXX,DC=XXXXXXX" --os-name="$PRETTY_NAME" --os-version="$VERSION" <DCNAME>
    responses:
        Password for *: "{{ username | b64decode }}"
```

Error:

```
TASK [adjoin : Join system to AD] ***********************************************************************************************************************************************************
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'item' is undefined\n\nThe error appears to be in '/tmp/ansiblepull/playbooks/roles/adjoin/tasks/main.yml': line 58, column 3, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n\n- name: Join system to AD\n  ^ here\n"}
```

Can anyone help me in solving this.

Comment: 1) loop is wrongly indented in your task: it is a task option, not an `expect` module option. 2) nothing to do with your current problem but good practice: don't install python modules with shell, use the [`pip` module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/pip_module.html).

Comment: Thanks @Zeitounator Can you give the commands example to use loop with expect module.

Comment: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html. TLDR; put loop at the end of your task, at the same indentation level as `expect` and `name`.

Comment: I do not see any example which talks about using multiple commands in expect module & how can we use loop with command & expect module ?

Comment: One simple way is to add those command to a script, push the script to the host and call that script in your expect module command. If you want to do something more fancy, read the [`expect` documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/expect_module.html), pay attention to the notes, move to the [`shell` module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/shell_module.html#shell-module) documentation and look for expect examples there.

Comment: This question has nothing to do with joining a domain or with the usage of `realm`. It's just a plain ansible usage problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first of all thanks everyone for the comments.

I have resolved it by using ansible_facts:

```
- name: install pexpect using pip
  pip:
    name: pexpect

- name: Join system to AD 
  expect:
    command: /bin/bash -c "realm join --membership-software=adcli --user=username@DOMAINNAME --computer-ou="OU={{ env }},OU={{ account }},OU=xxx,OU=xxxx,DC=xxxxx,DC=xxxx" --os-name={{ ansible_distribution }} --os-version={{ ansible_distribution_version }} DCNAME"
  responses:
        Password for *: "{{ join_user_pass | b64decode }}"
```